# Ubuntu 12.04 and Inspiron 6400

Tags: wireless, drivers, connection, inspiron

What driver do I need for Ubuntu 12.4 to work with a Dell Inspiron 6400?  I cannot get the wireless connection to work.  Then how do I install it?  I can't get the wireless connection to work. I just started using Ubuntu tonight and can't find instructions I can understand for accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your Dell with a WIRED internet-connection, and install the extra required driver (look for it in systemsettings/  additional drivers under hardware; the driver is (I've had the same model as you) one for Broadcom) . After installation reboot and connect to you Wifi-network.

You should come out fine by doing this action.